# Email Notification not sent only when a new order is placed in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, email-notifications

Email notification is not sending to the customer when new order is placed. But Email sent when invoice is generated or shipment done.

I have read lots of blog related that question and found many solution.

I almost tried all approach but not worked for me.